# Issue with React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

```
let todo=object=[]
todo=result
console.log(todo.firstItem)
```

I am trying to access `firstItem` property from the API response and facing this property issue:

```
Property 'firstItem' does not exist on type 'object'.  TS2339
```

Comment: try to run your code in console

Comment: i tried it in my local, it throws  Property 'firstItem' does not exist on type 'object'. TS2339 error, should i typecheck firstItem

Comment: Seems to me that `result` may not have a `firstItem` property. Try logging the value of `result`.

Comment: it has the value of firstItem

Comment: `let todo=object=[]` makes no sense, and neither does immediately reassigning it again with `todo=result`. If you have an API response, you either need to treat it as an `any` and "know" what to get out of it or create a `type` or `interface` from the API specs and *cast* the response to that type.

Comment: `type ToDoType = {firstItem: ItemType}; tet todo: ToDoType[];`